# How to use jQuery or javascript in html table body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement as follows. I am checking the user who has been logged in. Based on the userID, I want the save buttons to be enabled or disabled?

How can I check it using jQuery or javascript? My code is as follows.

```
// Function for getting userID based on name that has been existing in localstorage item.

function getUserIDbyName() {
        var username = localStorage.getItem("activeUser");
        var info = {
            uname: username
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUserIDByName", "MyWorkFlow")',
            data: info,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    document.getElementById("userID").value = data;
                }
            }
        });
    }



 My Html code:

     <td>
         <input type="hidden" id="userID" />
       </td>

    <td>
     @if(item.UID==1){   // I had hardcoded the value = 1 as of now. I want to check with value in $("userID").val(); which means I want to check like this if(item.UID==$("userID").val())
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="@item.ID" id="btnSubmit" onclick="fn(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
     }
    else{
   <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="@item.ID" id="btnSubmit" onclick="fn(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
    }
     </td>
```

Please help me

Comment: Sidenote: Just be sure that you check this on the serverside altso, or else everybody can use your save-button

Comment: @andreasnico: indeed. people can easily remove disabled attribute from console.

Comment: Only the activities which has been assigned to the logged user can click on save. Rest will be disabled. I need logic for this requirement, I am doing it on the client side itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button as disabled by default.  Like this:

```
<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="@item.ID" id="btnSubmit_@item.ID" onclick="fn(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
```

And then compare item id in success function. if UID is equal to user id, remove attribute disabled. And do make sure that both values are having same datatype before doing the comparison:

```
var UID = '@item.UID';
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUserIDByName", "MyWorkFlow")',
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                document.getElementById("userID").value = data;
                if(UID == data){//make sure both are having same datatype
                  $('.btn-sm[value='+ data +']').removeAttr("disabled");
                } 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am iterating through the data which contains list. If I do in the way you suggested all the buttons will be disabled.

Comment: @PSriharsha: well in that case you should find the button by their value(check edit above). as you got user id. and then enable it. also IDs should be unique in that case. not all buttons should have `btnSubmit` as id.